# is there a reason to not use an online uglifyjs minifier?

Tags: uglifyjs

Is there any reason *not* to use an online uglifyjs program like http://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/? Seems so much easier than installing it oneself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some security implications - you're basically not only showing a random third party (and additional listeners if it's not over TLS) your whole code but also trusting the third party and any attacker not to insert malicious content.

Additionally, the particular online service may be unreliable or be broken (hopefully in obvious ways of opposed to, say, only emitting the first 512 bytes). You're also out of luck if there is a routing problem on your end. Sometimes, it can also be quite slow - a local minification tool should be done within 0.1s, which is quite hard to do over the Internet, especially on a mobile connection.

But most importantly, if configured correctly, using an online service interactively should be *more*, not *less* work. Good software can be built and published automatically. If your build process entails manually copying code, pasting it somewhere, and then copying back the result, that's a lot of wasted time.

If you use a build process tool (like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or the venerable make), the minification can be done automatically, as one step in a large list.

Additionally, navigating to a website is harder than to hit the build button.

Finally, installation isn't that hard - have a look at [the instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js#install).

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

should be all you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.  For some reason, it won't install on my system (throws a bunch of errors).  But I'll pursue it on Monday with a fresh brain.  I appreciate your time & help.

Comment: Actually, I'll add in case you have any advice: I think it does, in fact install (if I use sudo) but then when I try to use it, I get a "-bash: uglifyjs: command not found" message.

Comment: The binary's name is `uglify`, not `uglifyjs`.

Comment: The instructions you cited say that the format is "uglifyjs [input files] [options]".  But even when I leave off the 'js' I get: "-bash: uglify: command not found".  (I'm assuming when you say "The binary" you mean the terminal command)

Comment: Whoa -- just started working -- and on a Friday afternoon no less.  Phihag -- thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right, `uglifyjs` is correct. Maybe you don't have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`? Try running `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` once, and then `uglifyjs`. Does that work?

Comment: Great to hear that it works for you! If this (or any other) answer solves your problem, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to indicate that to future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: I accepted your answer because it was totally right, but I'm going to quickly detail how I messed up here, just in case it helps anyone in the future:  1) I entered this into terminal: npm install uglify-js -g and it threw a bunch of errors; 2) I then tried the next line in the instructions: npm install uglify-js and it also threw a bunch of errors;  3) I then remembered I should put 'sudo' first, and I did this for number #2, when I should have done it for number #1.  As soon as I did it for #1 all was right in the world.